# Wordpress add image as background to dynamically created sections

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I am building a Wordpress theme that displays all my pages as sections on one single page and the menu scrolls to each section. For each section I want the user to be able to add a background image or background colour, but with the ability for them all to be different. However, with the code I am using, when you change the background-image for one page section - it changes it for all of them.

Is there a way I can change this code below so that when a user selects a background image (featured image) for a specific page, it ONLY changes the respective section.

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $slug = $page_data->post_name;
    //get url of featured image
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
    //check if page has featured image
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $featured_image = $thumb_url;
    }
    else {
$featured_image = '';
    }
    echo "<section id='$slug'  class='main fullscreen'>";
echo '<article class="main parallax" style="background:url(' . $featured_image . ') 50% 0 repeat fixed;">';
echo $content;
    echo '</article>';
echo "</section>";
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**
Changed my thumbnail logic to the following:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
```

foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $slug = $page_data->post_name;
    //get url of featured image

$background_image = '';
$background_image_array = get_the_post_thumbnail($page_data->ID, 'full');

```
echo "<section id='" . $slug  . "'  class='main fullscreen'>";
echo '<article class="main parallax" style="background:url(' . $background_image . ') 50% 0 repeat fixed;">';
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_data->ID, 'thumbnail'); 
echo $content;
echo '</article>';
echo "</section>";
}
?>
```

This will display the unique featured image for each page as a thumbnail above each page (because of the line `echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_data->ID, 'thumbnail');` However, I can't get the url of the image from this code....any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my updated answer:

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
  echo $image_url[0]
}
?>
```

You can put this in your loop at the required spot instead of echoing it, of course.

Here is the source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail (same as before)

And here is your code:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {    

  $featured_image_url = '';

  if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
  }

echo "<section id='" . $slug . "' class='main fullscreen'>";
echo '<article class="main parallax" style="background:url(' . $featured_image_url . ') 50% 0 repeat fixed;">';
echo $content;
echo '</article>';
echo "</section>";
}
?>
```

One side note:

```
echo "<section id='$slug'  class='main fullscreen'>";
```

...should use string concatenation as follows:

```
echo "<section id='" . $slug  . "'  class='main fullscreen'>";
```

Comment: Thanks for this (and for the $slug spot - hadn't seen that!). Can you elaborate a little on what I should be looking for on that page you linked to? or how I could be less roundabout with my method

Comment: Sure, sorry I wasn't more specific.

Delete all of your thumb logic, assign a default `$background_image` value of '' (empty, as in your `else` loop currently). Next, just assign this:
    `$background_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'full');`

Finally, assign the background image as you did in your loop, to the div generated by that iteration of the for loop.

Comment: I forgot a detail , you'll need to use `$page_data->ID` to define $post_id. This is referenced in the sample loop in the link to [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail), but it isn't obvious if you aren't totally familiar with the loop.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, getting there with this. page_data->ID was a lifesaver, can you check out my update above as I can't figure out how to get the URL of the image to display as the background url

Comment: No problem - I went to sleep and just finished brunch.  I updated my answer with another function to get the URL and also added your updated with my answer.  Can you mark as accepted once you verify it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $slug = $page_data->post_name;
    //get url of featured image


 $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );




    echo "<section id='$slug'  class='main fullscreen'>";
echo '<article class="main parallax" style="background:url(' . $image[0] . ') 50% 0 repeat fixed;">';
echo $content;
    echo '</article>';
echo "</section>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Annoyingly this still just shows the same featured image on all sections - really thought this one would work!

Comment: @SamSkirrow either tour content is diffrent on all sections?

Comment: Yes content is different on all sections

Comment: @SamSkirrow Then i think your featured image is same for all you posts/pages?

Comment: I've just double checked, and this is not the case, they are seperate featured images for each page. Strangely I've just noticed that the background image is always whatever the about page image is - it doesn't take into account any other page

Comment: @SamSkirrow now i have tested it on my local server it is working for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54331/discussion-between-mehar-and-sam-skirrow).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $slug = $page_data->post_name;
    //get url of featured image
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($page_data->ID);  // update
    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    if((isset($thumb_id) && $thumb_id != '')){
        $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
        $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
        echo "<section id='$slug'  class='main fullscreen'>";
                echo '<article class="main parallax" style="background:url(' . $thumb_url . ') 50% 0 repeat fixed;">';
            echo $content;
                echo '</article>';
          echo "</section>" ;  
     }
     else {
         echo "<section id='$slug'  class='main fullscreen'>";
                echo '<article class="main parallax" style="background:#fff;">';
            echo $content;
                echo '</article>';
          echo "</section>" ;
     }
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**
Changed my thumbnail logic to the following:

```
$post_id = $page->ID;
$background_image = '';
$background_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'full');
```

Comment: I'm afraid this answer still shows the same featured image on all page sections, not unique images for each section

Comment: I've just double checked, and this is not the case, they are seperate featured images for each page

Comment: You have to pass page id in `get_post_thumbnail_id` to get feature image for different pages, which i have updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use $page_data->ID as the $page_id. Then add that into the following code:

```
$background_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_data->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
```

Works like a charm